# Check if a function has been called, Angular unit testing

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have called a function inside ngOnInit,

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.isSubscribable();
}
```

I wan to do unit testing for this ngOnInit like this:

```
    it('Check isSubscribable is called from ngOnInit', async(async() => {
      spyOn(component, 'isSubscribable').and.callThrough();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      await fixture.whenStable();
      expect(component.isSubscribable).toHaveBeenCalled();

    }))
```

This is not working. I need some help on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What if you try like this ?

```js
it('Check isSubscribable is called from ngOnInit', () => {
  const spySubscribable = spyOn(component, 'isSubscribable');
  component.ngOnInit();
  expect(spySubscribable).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got Function.
 Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalled()
     at Object.eval (./src/lib/custom-ui-compo

Comment: yup, it works, but why fixture.detectChanges not work?

Comment: That's not absolutely clear to me. But I think given that you don't have any asynchronous task, you don't  need to detect changes, either to use async/await.

Answer (score 2):

```
it('Check isSubscribable is called from ngOnInit', () => {
  const spy = spyOn(component, 'isSubscribable').and.callThrough();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
}))
```

You only need to manually call `fixture.detectChanges()` if your component has `changeDetection` set to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.

The above should work assuming that you have instantiated the component properly before the `it` assertion kicks in, like:

```
let component: MyComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
})
```

If your code is that simple that you have only this method call in `ngOnInit()` then you might not need to use any `async/await` and `.whenStable` magic.